# Stop smartphone microphone from listening in background

Tags: privacy, android, mobile, ios

Recently it has come to light that tech companies such as Facebook and Microsoft use humans to listen and transcribe audio conversations on [Facebook messenger](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/facebook-also-hired-human-contractors-to-listen-to-audio-from-its-messenger-app/ar-AAFL359) and [Skype](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jaymcgregor/2019/08/07/microsoft-workers-are-listening-to-some-skype-calls-leak-reveals) to improve their AI. However this only occurs when the app is active.

I'm a little concerned if it is possible for applications to listen to background conversations. Like some apps using [Alphonso software](https://techcrunch.com/2018/01/02/some-apps-were-listening-to-you-through-the-smartphones-mic-says-report/) listened to TV noise in the background using the smartphone's mic.

Is it possible to prevent apps from accessing the phone's microphone in background but still allow microphone use when using the app (e.g. making a Skype call)? Perhaps through an app/operating system which notifies you when your microphone is in use?

Comment: Android and iOS can restrict the execution of apps in background. This applies to the whole app, not only to the microphone, but maybe it's enough for you.